# Getting Syntax error while creating this procedure

Tags: mysql

MYSQL VERSION - 5.7.12

I am getting syntax error when creating this procedure .
I have added code for creating table and then called this procedure.

```
-- create table
CREATE TABLE ResumeActivityLog ( Email VARCHAR(255),
ProfileID int (11),
ExternalUserDID VARCHAR(255),
EventType VARCHAR(255),
ResumeDID VARCHAR(255), 
EventText VARCHAR(255),
CreatedOn DATETIME);

-- create procedure
CREATE  PROCEDURE `SaveMultipleResumeActivityLog`(
    _resumeDIDs           Text
)
    INSERT INTO `ResumeActivityLog` (`Email`,`ProfileID`,`ExternalUserDID`, `EventType`, `ResumeDID`, `EventText`, `CreatedOn`)
    SELECT "", 0, "", "resume_anon_delete", ResumeDID,  "success", CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    FROM JSON_TABLE(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(_resumeDIDs, ',', '","'), '"]'),
                    '$[*]' COLUMNS (ResumeDID VARCHAR(255) PATH '$')) jsontable;

-- call procedure with CSV as a parameter
CALL SaveMultipleResumeActivityLog('R2W5D16T8BRYWZKRF28,RHL1B05ZTQ546JKF0RG,RD95SY747Z89M7GN8TP,R2N54T767CZTBY79N00,RHT2GR6K0FTYTPFG985,RDH4KV5Z3WX7SV2850N');

-- check for the result
SELECT * FROM ResumeActivityLog;
```

[image]

Comment: json_TABLe is only valid for mysql 8 in its later versions, mysql 5.7 doesn't support it

Comment: MYSQL VERSION - 5.7.12 @nbk, what alternative i can do

Comment: mariadb 10.6 or mysql 8 here you can try versions out https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2fd20e6024e1137b5bbf97d656e5d125

Comment: how can i change the procedure to achieve  the same @nbk

Comment: but there are other solutions as well when you search for it